# Moving a screenshot from Persistent Data Path to Gallery - Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, android-permissions, persistent-storage

I've been using the script below to take a screenshot, save it to the persistent data path, then move it to the gallery and refresh the gallery.

When testing on Samsung Gallery S8 and Samsung Tab S5e, this works perfectly; I take a screenshot then I can view it in the devices gallery.

However, I've now tested it on Samsung Galaxy A50, and it doesn't work (I've also had reports from other people who have the same issue). It saves to the Persistent Data Path but is unable to move it to the DCIM/Camera folder, giving the error:

```
2020-12-04 10:51:56.345 6166-6251/? E/Unity: UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
      at System.IO.File.Move (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
      at SaveGallery+<CRSaveScreenshot>d__2.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
      at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
     
    (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

myDefaultLocation returns a pathway of:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/BUNDLEIDENTIFIER/files/Screenshot104958.jpg
```

myScreenshotLocation returns a pathway of:

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Screenshot104958.jpg
```

Here's the script I'm using:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;

public class SaveGallery : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        if (Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite))
        {
            // The user authorized use of the External Storage.
        }
        else
        {
            // We do not have permission to use the External Storage.
            // Ask for permission or proceed without the functionality enabled.
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite);
        }
    }
    public void TakePhoto(){
        StartCoroutine(CRSaveScreenshot());
    }
   IEnumerator CRSaveScreenshot() 
 { 
     yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
 
      string myFileName = "Screenshot" + System.DateTime.Now.Hour + System.DateTime.Now.Minute + System.DateTime.Now.Second + ".jpg";
      string myDefaultLocation = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + myFileName;
      string myFolderLocation = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/";  //EXAMPLE OF DIRECTLY ACCESSING A CUSTOM FOLDER OF THE GALLERY
      string myScreenshotLocation = myFolderLocation + myFileName;
      Debug.Log("I WANT TO SAVE TO " + myScreenshotLocation);
 
      //ENSURE THAT FOLDER LOCATION EXISTS
      if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(myFolderLocation))
      {
          System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(myFolderLocation);
      }
 
      ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(myFileName);
      //MOVE THE SCREENSHOT WHERE WE WANT IT TO BE STORED
 
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
 
      System.IO.File.Move(myDefaultLocation, myScreenshotLocation);

        using (AndroidJavaClass jcUnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
        using (AndroidJavaObject joActivity = jcUnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
        using (AndroidJavaObject joContext = joActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext"))
        using (AndroidJavaClass jcMediaScannerConnection = new AndroidJavaClass("android.media.MediaScannerConnection"))
        using (AndroidJavaClass jcEnvironment = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Environment"))
        using (AndroidJavaObject joExDir = jcEnvironment.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getExternalStorageDirectory"))
        {
            jcMediaScannerConnection.CallStatic("scanFile", joContext, new string[] { myScreenshotLocation }, null, null);
        }
 }
}
```

Why does this seem to work on some Samsung devices but not other ones?

Comment: Have you also added that permission to your manifest file ?

Comment: On an Android 10 device now?

Comment: `Taking a screenshot and saving to gallery - Android` Wrong subject. You are just trying to copy a file.

Comment: I have these permissions in my Manisfest:  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

The device is running Android 10

Comment: Your Android 10 problem has been reported yesterday and all days before. Three months long. Read pages stackoverflow tagged `android`.